# Excel userform - populate textbox based on combobox selection

Tags: combobox

I am developing a small project, but my knowledge in vba is still a little limited, so I would like to ask for your help.

The project is in excel and the database in access:

Table1 with 3 fields: Brand, Model and Port

Apple / iPhone XR / Lighning
Samsung / Galaxy A42 / usb-c
Xiaomi / Redmi / usb-c

Code in userform:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call Brand
End Sub


Private Sub comboBrand_Change()
    
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Module1.ConnectBD  
    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM Table1", Conexao, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
    
        txtModel.Value = rs(2)

    If Not rs Is Nothing Then
        
            rs.Close
            Set rs = Nothing
    
    End If
 
    Module1.DisconnectBD

End Sub


Sub Brand()

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Module1.ConnectBD
    
    rs.Open "SELECT DISTINCT brand FROM Table1 ORDER BY brand ASC", Conexao, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
    
    Do Until rs.EOF
    
        comboBrand.AddItem rs!Brand
        
        rs.MoveNext
        
    Loop
           
    If Not rs Is Nothing Then
        
            rs.Close
            Set rs = Nothing
    
    End If
                    
    Module1.DisconnectBD

End Sub
```

What I want is that every time I change the value in the ComboBox, the textbox Model updates according to the table; but the only value I can get is always the first line, that is "iPhone XR", no matter what I put in the combobox.
I know I have to reference the line with what is selected in the combobox but I can't get there; can you help?

Answer (score 0):

After a few more attempts I finally found the solution:

```
Private Sub comboBrand_Change()

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Module1.ConnectBD

    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE brand ='" & UserForm1.comboBrand.Text & "'", Conexao, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
        
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    
        UserForm1.txtModel = rs!Model
        UserForm1.txtPort = rs!Port
        UserForm1.txtID = rs!ID
        
    Else
    
        MsgBox "Not found!", vbInformation, "Brand"
    
    End If
    
    If Not rs Is Nothing Then
    
        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
    
    End If

    Module1.DisconnectBD

    Exit Sub

End Sub
```